# How to move inline menu list next to Burger Bar (Menu Bar) On right hand Side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu

I am trying to move the inline menu next to the burger bar on the right hand side of the page. I am using bootsrtap, the image below is how I want the menu to appear, is it possible? So when the user clicks the burger bar the menu comes out on the left next to the burger bar. At the moment it drops down below the menu bar. Here is the bootsnip http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/M3gdX example.

[image]

Below is my code (HTML):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img id="header-image">Logo</a>         
</div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="menu-bar"></div>
            <div class="menu-bar"></div>
            <div class="menu-bar"></div>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="number-list">
          <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>                             
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS code:

```
.menu-bar {
width: 22px;
height: 2px;
background-color: white;
margin: 6px ;
border-radius: 1px;
}
#number-list.dropdown-menu {
width: 300px;
}
.dropdwon-toggle {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I am new to this and can't seem to find anywhere an example of a drop left menu that doesn't slide out the page or come over the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set float: left to your li elements to make it horizontal in one line.

```
<ul class="list-inline lefties">

    <li class="active lefties-item">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="lefties-item">
        <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>

    <li class="lefties-item">
        <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>

    <li class="lefties-item">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>       

    <li class="lefties-item">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
  ul.lefties:after {
      clear: both;
      display: block;
      content: "";
  }

 .lefties-item {
     float: left;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still displays it below the burger bar inline as in my example before. I have updated the bootsnip http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/M3gdX so you can have a look as see it. I have been searching for an answer for two weeks now.